# Jade "attributes" not working in mixin

Tags: attributes, pug, mixins

I'm using Jade 1.3.0 on Laravel. I have this mixin defined:

```
mixin ShotPreview()
    div(attributes).shot-preview.tile
        each n in [1,2,3]
            div.tile-content
                img(src="/thumbs/{{shot.id}}_#{n}.jpg")
        if(block)
            block
```

And I'm calling it like

```
+ShotPreview()(data-role="live-tile" data-effect="fade" ng-class="{'selected': shot.selected}" ng-click="shot.selected=!shot.selected").live.double
```

However, the root div element of my mixin gets rendered as

```
<div attributes="attributes" class="shot-preview tile">
```

And I have no idea why. There are no errors and the syntax looks okay to me.
I'm new to Jade so I suppose it's something silly but I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use the new syntax, to pass the attributes to a element

```
div&attributes(attributes).shot-preview.tile
```

see the discussion here: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1294

Comment: God, I was just about to give up at Google page 7 or something... thanks man!